# Wipers wont remove water in one area of windshield

Tags: maintenance

when raining and I turn on my wipers they remove water from all areas of windshield except for one area in my view, after wiping across this area,the water is still there and I can't see the road in that area when this happens. Why?

Comment: Perhaps worn wiper blades that need replacing, or is the type with a spoiler that is supposed to add pressure, but has been fitted the wrong way and lifts it instead, or it needs a new spring, or the pivot is siezed and needs easing...

Comment: ...or there is silicone wax on that area of the screen, although in this case the wipers do move the water, but the problem is that the glass smears making it hard to see.

Comment: If the blades are a year old , replace them and then look to see if there is a problem.